# Is it possible to insert sql query in php array value?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, subquery, sql-insert

```
for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_sub_category"]); $count++)
{
    $data = array(
        ':item_sub_category_id' 
             => SELECT r_name FROM Repair where r_id = $_POST["item_sub_category"][$count]
    );

    $query = "INSERT INTO Repairlog (description,visitID) VALUES (:item_sub_category_id,'1')";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($data);

}
```

Comment: Are you trying the use the result of the SELECT query as an input to the INSERT query? It's a bit unclear. But if so, you can write that as one single SQL statement. The way you're doing it now, the SELECT query will not be executed. You've parameterised it so it'll be treated as a string. Even if it wasn't, it still would not be valid SQL. Google for "insert...select" syntax to get the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

As far as concerns, your code won't work. The SQL query that you are passing as a parameter will simply be interpreted as a string.

You could avoid the need for a loop by taking advantage of the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` syntax. The idea is to generate an `IN` clause that contains all values that are in the array, and then run a single query to insert all records at once.

Consider:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($_POST["item_sub_category"]) - 1) . '?';
$query = "INSERT INTO Repairlog (description,visitID) SELECT r_name, 1 FROM Repair WHERE r_id IN ($in)";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($_POST["item_sub_category"]);
```

Note: it is likely that `visitID` is an integer and not a string; if so, then it is better not to surround the value with single quotes (I removed them in the above code).

Comment: maybe do the select into a temporary table first and insert the temporary table data if the copied data is a large set.. The general idea is to release the row (table/index) [locks](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/) faster on the repair table assuming InnoDB here and a copied dataset which can fit in a memory table offcource otherwise you would still have to deal with disk I/O as it would become a disk based temporary table

Comment: @RaymondNijland: right... But on the other hand this technique would create some kind of race condition where records modified in `Repair` after the copy to the temp table would not be taken into account by the `INSERT` query...

Comment: *"But on the other hand this technique would create some kind of race condition where records modified in Repair after the copy to the temp table would not be taken into account by the INSERT query..."* .... `INSERT INTO Repairlog (description,visitID) SELECT r_name, 1 FROM Repair WHERE r_id IN ($in)`  would also not taken in account coping changes after running the `INSERT`..  Also that is not something you would call race condition..

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; No.

Your question can be re-framed as: *Can I write `SQL` code in `php`*. The answer is NO. You can write the `SQL` code within a `String` type variable (or parameter) in `php`.

This is a general rule for any programming language, you cannot have multiple languages within the same file, as the language [`parser`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser) will not be able understand which syntax is that.

In order to embed a different language in another language, you need some kind of separator that will define when the new *language* or special *type* will start and when it will end.